# Repairing Ipad mini 3 wifi

Tags: ipad, wifi, repair

My ipad wifi "switch" does not work, even after a complete reinstall. Is this something I could buy a spare part and repair my self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wifi 'switch' is in the iOS software, and it is certainly not a discrete physical object that can be replaced.

From the [iFixit teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPad+Mini+3+Wi-Fi+Teardown/30628) of this particular iPad, you can see that replacing the wi-fi chip itself is next to impossible to repair or replace. iPad logic boards are replaced in their entirety, and individual modules (like wi-fi chips) cannot be swapped.

[image]